# A query about generalizing the complex field

Tags: complex-analysis, field-theory

The complex field is formed by considering the set of ordered pairs of real numbers $\{(a,b):\,a \in \mathbb{R},\,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and assigning upon it the two operations $+$ and $\cdot$ defined as follows
$$(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c\,,\,b+d)$$
$$(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac-bd\,,\,ad+bc)$$
My question is, does there exist any *useful* system where one can generalize this field to obtain a general field $\mathbb{F}$ by considering the set of ordered *n-tuples* of real numbers $\{(a_1,\ldots,a_n):\,a_i \in \mathbb{R},\,i=1,\ldots,n\}$ and assigning upon them some properly defined operations $+$ and $\cdot$ such that $(\mathbb{F},+,\cdot)$ is a field?

My guess is that, either any system with such a field should simplify down to a system which is based on the usual real or complex fields, or such a generalized field will be too weird to have useful applications. But I cannot find a precise argument for that. Any clarification in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Useful may depend on the beholder...yet you can google "Hamilton quaternions". Not a field but a division ring, or a skew-field.

Comment: For set-theoretical reasons, the field structures on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are (non-canonically) in bijection if we make no compatibility restrictions; do you want to assume that your field is an algebra over $\mathbb{R}$? Then the question becomes answerable...

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks. This is the extension I was looking for.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomplex_number.

Comment: @lhf Thanks for the link. That's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Frobenius proved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)) that

> The only finite-dimensional associative division algebras over the real numbers are the real numbers, the complex numbers, and the quaternions.

The more general notion is [hypercomplex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomplex_number), which sacrifices other properties such as associativity.